# How to remove black area below/above metricsgraphs.js line graph?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, metricsgraphicsjs

I'm trying to learn how to use metricsgraphs.js library and I have a problem with line graphs.
I tried to draw basic line graph in the same way that it's instructed in metricsgraphicsjs.org examples, but there is some mysterious black area over/sometimses under(depends on data) my graph and I don't have a clue how to remove it or why it's there.

This is what I have imported in my html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="kirjastot/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="kirjastot/tooltip.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="kirjastot/d3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="kirjastot/popper.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="kirjastot/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="kirjastot/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="kirjastot/mg/MG.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="kirjastot/mg/common/brush.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="kirjastot/mg/common/chart_title.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="kirjastot/mg/common/data_graphic.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="kirjastot/mg/common/hooks.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="kirjastot/mg/common/init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="kirjastot/mg/common/markers.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="kirjastot/mg/common/register.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="kirjastot/mg/common/rollover.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="kirjastot/mg/common/scales.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="kirjastot/mg/common/window_listeners.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="kirjastot/mg/common/x_axis.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="kirjastot/mg/common/y_axis.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="kirjastot/mg/common/zoom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="kirjastot/mg/charts/bar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="kirjastot/mg/charts/histogram.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="kirjastot/mg/charts/line.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="kirjastot/mg/charts/missing.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="kirjastot/mg/charts/point.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="kirjastot/mg/charts/table.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="kirjastot/mg/layout/button.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="kirjastot/mg/misc/error.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="kirjastot/mg/misc/formatters.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="kirjastot/mg/misc/markup.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="kirjastot/mg/misc/process.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="kirjastot/mg/misc/smoothers.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="kirjastot/mg/misc/transitions.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="kirjastot/mg/misc/utility.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="kirjastot/mg/common/bootstrap_tooltip_popover.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="kirjastot/mg/layout/bootstrap_dropdown.js"></script>
```

And this is how I'm drawing graph in javascript:

```
var data = [{ temperature: 20, time: 1 }, { temperature: 20, time: 2 }, { temperature: 29, time: 3 }, { temperature: 10, time: 4 }, { temperature: 5, time: 5 }];
MG.data_graphic({
    title: "Line",
    data: data,
    area: false,
    target: '#testi',
    x_accessor: 'time',
    y_accessor: 'temperature',
});
```

And result looks like this:

[Result line graph with random black area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyKOY.png)

Has someone faced similar behaviour with metricsgraphs? What is that black area? Or does someone know some good examples about metricsgraph.js other than its own webpage?(For example some examples about bar graphs)

Comment: That's probably the missing stylesheet or missing styling of the <path> element. The <path> should be styled somthing like: path {
    fill: none;
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
  }

Comment: now I feel stupid :D It was exactly missing stylesheet that caused problem. When added <link rel="stylesheet" href="metricsgraphics.css"> graph is drawn as it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding missing stylelsheet metricsgraphics.css solves the problem.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="metricsgraphics.css">
```